# R shiny navbarPage right aligned tabs

Tags: r, shiny

By default, using `navbarPage()` in shiny creates a 'static top' bootstrap page ([example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/)).  If I were writing the html for a webpage, I could add a `<ul>` element with a class of `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` where the `navbar-right` would move the tabs/menus to the right side of the navbar.

There doesn't seem to be a way to coerce this behavior directly through the framework - is there a clever known way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how low your expectations are.

You can add css to your UI which aligns either your tabsets or your header to the right. Code:

```
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
          .navbar .navbar-nav {float: right}
          .navbar .navbar-header {float: right}
        "))
      ),
      navbarPage("header",
        tabPanel("tab1"),
        tabPanel("tab2")
      )
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){}

)

runApp(app)
```

**Edit:** The `header` argument of `navbarPage` also accepts regular `div`-containers. (E.g. a logo instead of plain text.) This can be exploitet to fill whole UI-Elements (e.g. buttons) into the `header` spot. Then of course you can float that to the right, while your tabs are aligned to the left.

Comment: In this method, all tabs move to the right, correct?

Comment: @Mark Correct. I don't know if there is any way to define float on each tab seperately.

Comment: @Mark Maybe exploit the `header` as explained in the edit.

Answer (score 5):

The solution provided by K. Rohde, especially the edit, works for keeping it nearly pure Shiny.  I discovered the `insertAdjacentHTML` javascript function and used it to create a right-hand text label. I guess it should be possible to make tabs that Shiny knows about and can use.  In my case, I was wanting to put version information on the navbar, on the right-hand side.  So, adding the `disabled` class was to avoid confusion.

```
library(shiny)
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      navbarPage("Site Title",
        tabPanel("v0.1"),
        tabPanel("tab1"),
        tabPanel("tab2")
      ),
      HTML("<script>var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-nav');
parent[0].insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterend', '<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\"><li class=\"disabled\"><a href=\"#\">v0.1</a></li></ul>' );</script>")
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){}

)

runApp(app)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use shinyjs package

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(

    navbarPage(
        'Test',
        id = 'menus',
        tabPanel('Test',
                 shinyjs::useShinyjs()),
        tabPanel("Summary"),
        tabPanel("Table", value = 'table')
    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    shinyjs::addClass(id = "menus", class = "navbar-right")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```